# Why is classList.remove is not working but jQuery .removeClass is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, addeventlistener

I'm still getting used to plain JavaScript and creating a basic set of square shaped divs that will add and remove classes when clicked. I'm using an array that will add a specific one of those classes. When clicking, I'd like to remove all of those classes before adding a new one. So for example, when clicking on the 2nd square, 'classB' will be added to only that one and then clicking any others will remove it.

I understand that `classList.remove` has to be before `classList.add` but for some reason it is not working. I always get the message "Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined at HTMLDivElement.elem.addEventListener".

However, if I use jQuery .`removeClass` it works with no problem. But I'd prefer not to use jQuery.

Here's the snippet. You can see the `classList.remove` that I was trying in what's commented out.

```js
const addClass = ['classA','classB','classC','classD'];
const numbers = [0,1,2,3];
const square = document.querySelectorAll('.square');

square.forEach((elem, i) => {

  elem.addEventListener('click', () => {

    //square[i].classList.remove(...addClass)
    $(square).removeClass('classA classB classC classD');

    if (i == numbers[i]) {
      elem.classList.add(addClass[i]);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.square {
width: 2rem;
height: 2rem;
background-color: black;
margin: 1rem;
}

.classA { background-color: red; }
.classB { background-color: yellow; }
.classC { background-color: green; }
.classD { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

I've looked through a bunch of other questions in here and on other sites but am not really seeing it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to call `classList.remove()` on `square` and not on `elem`?

Comment: It's because `square` is a NodeList. Try `this.classList.remove()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 methods you are comparing are not equivalent:

```js
square[i].classList.remove(...addClass)
```

Will remove all of the classes in the array from **one** element.

```js
$(square).removeClass('classA classB classC classD');
```

Will remove all of those classes from **all** the squares.

To do this without jQuery you could do:

```js
square.forEach(elem => elem.classList.remove(...addClass));
```

```js
const addClass = ['classA','classB','classC','classD'];
const numbers = [0,1,2,3];
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
// renamed square to squares so it's more obvious that it is a NodeList and not a single Node

squares.forEach((elem, i) => {

  elem.addEventListener('click', () => {

    squares.forEach(elem => elem.classList.remove(...addClass));

    if (i == numbers[i]) {
      elem.classList.add(addClass[i]);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.square {
width: 2rem;
height: 2rem;
background-color: black;
margin: 1rem;
}

.classA { background-color: red; }
.classB { background-color: yellow; }
.classC { background-color: green; }
.classD { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: They want it inside the click event though (I assume based on code).

Comment: @EternalHour Yes, I updated my answer with a snippet.